# ALCATEL Modem compatibility on UB 12.04

Tags: 12.04, usb-modem, usb-modeswitch, alcatel

Reciently updated to UB12.04 from previous version.
When done, my alcatex onetouch x220Y 3g modem does not work anymore.
How can I fix this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Provide output from; **lsusb | grep 1bbb**

Comment: Same issue as: http://askubuntu.com/questions/131407/dodo-usb-modem-alcatel-onetouch-x220l-not-working-since-update-to-12-04

Answer (score 3):

Open up a terminal from Applications -> Accessories. Type:

```
gksu gedit /etc/modules
```

At the bottom of the file, make two new lines, like this:

```
usbserial
option
```

Then close the editor program and save it. Reboot the computer and hopefully you’ll be right from now on!

Comment: Where has this worked?  What source can you cite?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, this worked for me for ClubTelco/Dodo USB Modem (Alcatel 'OneTouch X220L'):

```
Vendor=1bbb ProdID=0017 Rev=00.00
1bbb:0017 T & A Mobile Phones
```

I also needed to clear some of my other attempts using:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome
```