# Dodo USB Modem (Alcatel 'OneTouch X220L') not working since update to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, configuration, usb-modem, usb-modeswitch

I have a dodo USB modem in which I had used perfectly fine in 11.10. When I first installed Ubuntu I plugged the USB modem in and it worked perfectly as is.

However, since the new update it will not do such, I've tried updating all the software and what not, updated `usb-modeswitch`, tried `ndiswrapper` (although, it was worth a shot) and yet nothing works still.

I have also used lsusb as per on the [MobileWirelessBroadband](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MobileWirelessBroadband) page and it is apparently there.

```
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 1bbb:0017 T & A Mobile Phones
```

Not sure if I'm missing anything, so just thought I'd ask. ;-)

Comment: From http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Mobile_Broadband#ALCATEL this is a **Alcatel** 'OneTouch X220L'

Answer (score 1):

Followed Instructions here.
[ALCATEL Modem compatibility on UB 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130295/alcatel-modem-compatibility-on-ub-12-04)

I must unplug and replug in my dodo usb key (One Touch AL720) for it to be recognized each time I turn on PC.

Answer (score 0):

*Warning: This could be time-consuming, so please be patient.*

Uninstall each update and see if it works if it doesn't work reinstall the update. Then file a bug report mentioning the version of your operating system and the update on Launchpad.