# Alcatel X215 3G no longer works in 12.04 (no /dev/ttyUSB*)

Tags: 12.04, usb-modem, 3g, usb-modeswitch, alcatel

I just upgraded my netbook from Ubuntu 11.xx to 12.04 and after that I could not use my Alcatel X215 3G modem any more.
With the former version of Ubuntu, I had installed the `driver-tool` package from Alcatel plus `usb-modeswitch` and `wdial`. All worked perfectly.
After the upgrade no way. I could not find any trace of `/dev/ttyUSB*` in the file system.

How can I get my modem to work in 12.04?

Comment: Provide output from; **lsusb | grep 1bbb**

Comment: Same issue as: http://askubuntu.com/questions/131407/dodo-usb-modem-alcatel-onetouch-x220l-not-working-since-update-to-12-04

Comment: @david6 That's a different modem. Are you sure this is a duplicate?

Comment: It may not be a true **duplicate** question, but is likely the same issue.  If this user posted the **lsusb** output for their Alcatel modem (eg. 1bbb:????), it would be much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions below and got X220L work after restart.

[ALCATEL Modem compatibility on UB 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130295/alcatel-modem-compatibility-on-ub-12-04)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.