# Getting an Alcatel X220L connected

Tags: modem, 3g, alcatel

I am new to Ubuntu and I have an Alcatel X220L 3G modem that I need to get to work. My Ubuntu version is 14.04. Can anyone explain to me step-by-step how to configure this modem on this operating system?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try: http://askubuntu.com/questions/130295/alcatel-modem-compatibility-on-ub-12-04

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this side helps you: http://linuxtricksandtips.blogspot.de/2010/12/how-to-use-alcatel-one-touch-x220l-3g.html
I haven't tested the instructions given on that site but it looks right because the instructions are almost identical to the steps required to get an iPhone working as an 3g modem with ubuntu.

Comment: +1 it is much easier to eject the virtual CD bundled within the flash memory of the modem, i had to usb_modeswitch everytime i plug the modem, now i use this rule in the `/etc/udev/rules.d/`
`KERNEL=="sr1",ACTION=="add",RUN+="/usr/bin/eject /dev/sr1"`